# Turn off the Cell Radio?

Tags: audio, chromecast, zooming

Any way to simply turn off the cell phone radio?

This need has come up in ZOOM sessions using the zoom app because that app uses the "phone audio" rather than "media audio"

As a result, it is impossible to include meeting audio if you ChromeCast the session.  The video works, but the audio only outputs using the phone's speaker or audio jack.  Testing using an android tablet rather than an android phone shows that since the tablet does not have a cellular radio, the meeting audio is cast with the video.

Airplane mode is not an option since that would prevent connecting to the internet.

In addition, trying to address the audio using a bluetooth speaker doesn't work either... while it's possible to initially send bluetooth audio to the speaker, something unknown turns that off after a few minutes.

Any thoughts on addressing this would be appreciated.
Beverly Howard

Comment: Have you tried: enable Airplane mode and then in settings enable WiFi before the call?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just finished a long test session using ZOOM in an attempt to setup a ChromeCast viewing session with ChromeCast transmitting both video and audio ;

android cellphone
OS 8.1.0

The goal was to be able to participate in a remote class using a cellphone and ChromeCast to enable the use a large screen

ChromeCast "mirror screen" works to get the phone video mirrored on the large screen, but the Zoom App only uses the "Call Audio" which is not seen by ChromeCast

Connecting to a Vizio soundbar and connecting via bluetooth does not project the Zoom audio

Using a Bluetooth headset does connect to the Zoom Audio (this is probably bluetooth device specific)

It is also possible to use the phone's audio jack to connect and amplify the Zoom audio output.

Using Airplane Mode did not address Zoom App's use of "Call Audio"

Removing the Sim Card did not address Zoom App's use of "Call Audio"

It has been suggested that using a mobile browser app for the zoom interface might also work... have not tested that yet.

Hope this info will be helpful to others with the same need.

Beverly Howard